# No 'modules.conf' found, no modules will be loaded

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asterisk, ubuntu-14.04

I am try install asterisk in Ubuntu 14.04 and i have a problem whit asterisk 11 but is equal problem whit asterisk 13. He write next message:

```
Could not find valid ccss.conf file. Using cc_max_requests default
    Could not find valid ccss.conf file. Using cc_[state]_devstate defaults
     Asterisk Dynamic Loader Starting:
    No 'modules.conf' found, no modules will be loaded. <-- this error
    Asterisk Ready.
```

I try :

1. Reinstall the application <-- Not work
2. List item whit :

   > ```
   > *CLI> sip show peers
   >
   > No such command 'sip show peers' (type 'core show help sip show' for other possible commands)
   >
   > *CLI> module show
   >
   > Module                         Description                              Use Count  Status      Support Level
   > 0 modules loaded
   >
   > *CLI> module load chan_sip.so
   >
   > SIP channel loading...
   >
   > Unable to load config sip.conf
   >
   > No 'sip' message technology found.
   >
   > Unable to load module chan_sip.so
   >
   > Command 'module load chan_sip.so' failed.
   > ```
3. Read the file asterisk.conf and sarch any problem.

   [directories](!)
   astetcdir => /home/jose/root/etc/asterisk 
   astmoddir => /home/jose/root/lib/asterisk/modules
   astvarlibdir => /home/jose/root/var/lib/asterisk
   astdbdir => /home/jose/root/var/lib/asterisk
   astkeydir => /home/jose/root/var/lib/asterisk
   astdatadir => /home/jose/root/var/lib/asterisk
   astagidir => /home/jose/root/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin
   astspooldir => /home/jose/root/var/spool/asterisk
   astrundir => /home/jose/root/var/run/asterisk
   astlogdir => /home/jose/root/var/log/asterisk
   astsbindir => /home/jose/root/sbin
4. I execute :

   sudo asterisk -vvvcC /home/jose/root/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf

and not go.

Any idea guys.

Comment: According to this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/asterisk - a pre-built asterisk package for Ubuntu appears to exist already. Any particular reason you're trying to reinvent this wheel, instead of simply installing the distribution-built asterisk package?

Comment: Nice , go asterisk. But in my university use manual installation packets , asterisk 11 and qlite 3.

Comment: Then you should expect your university to provide technical support for their custom packages. Nobody other than your university knows exactly how their custom installation package works.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
[directories](!)
```

mean section template. so you have no any settings in your asterisk.conf(just one template which never used) and it work with default settings.

so please change that or put /etc/asterisk/modules.conf

Comment: Not go , whit this mode , is equal.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. You need REMOVE "(!)". Your current config equal to empty one